# Phonon dispersion calculation error

Tags: quantum-espresso, phonon-dispersion

I am getting the following error

error in routine phq_readin (1):
reading xq

I don't understand what is this error about.

Comment: Could you include the input file you are using as a code block so that other users can test it to diagnose where the error is coming from?

Comment: @Tyberius Sir give me some time. I lost some data, I will post when i recover it. But if there are some general solutions which anyone must have seen, they are most welcome.

Comment: @epsilon02fft I gave you a +1 but did you find the lost data? Perhaps we should close this until you've found it?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes, Please close this question.